# PHPMailer With AJAX Does Not Send Attachments

Tags: php, ajax, forms, phpmailer, attachment

I'm using PHPMailer on a simple contact form, and to submit that form I'm using jQuery AJAX. The contact form works as expected along with AJAX, and now that everything is working I'm tackling this issue.

File attachments aren't included in the email sent by PHPMailer when submitting the form via AJAX.

How can I also send attachments when submitting the form with jQuery AJAX?

Comment: PHPMailer has nothing to do with Ajax. You're simply handling the uploads wrong. Base your code on the multiple file upload example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: You might find PHP is changing the form-4-file to form_4_file. This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436166/php-replace-dashes-in-object-variables-with-underscores

Comment: What does this mean? I can't name my input fields with '-'? Is this why my attachments aren't sent?

Comment: It may be the filenames that are causing the problem. If you have tested that the `if( isset($_FILES['form-4-file']) && $_FILES['form-4-file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK )` does work - by echoing "it works" for example, then try echoing the file names. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php might also help.

Comment: The files are received when I disable AJAX. The PHP part of the attachment is working, It's when the form is submitted with AJAX that the attachments don't work. I don't receive the echo when form is submitted with ajax

Comment: Solve one problem at a time - upload your files, then mail them. If you try to do both at once and it doesn't work, you don't know where the problem is. It sounds like you need to log precisely what is turning up in your ajax submission.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set headers of mail. Some of header examples are below:-

```
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
```

Comment: at least mime-version, content-type, content-transfer-encoding, content-disposition should be there

Comment: PHPMailer deals with all that for you, no need to do all that.